# Weird extension method issue with inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend Page class to add some new functionality (ease of use for some methods as they will be called directly within the code of that page) in ASP.NET, and I'm getting a weird error:

My method is called `SetQuery`,
if I type `SetQuery` in a Page class, it is not recognized (yes, I've added `using [Namespace];`),
if I type `base.SetQuery` it is seen in IntelliSense, but doesn't compile saying no method or extension method is actually found in Page,
if I type `(this as Page).SetQuery` it is recognized and works.

Especially the second case seems to be a bug to me, as IntelliSense recognizes it as an extension method, but no compilation.

Is there any 'more natural' way to type SetQuery as I go, without casts etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extension methods *always* require an (explicit) target object, so it is impossible to call an extension method via just `TheMethodName()`. I suspect that if you type:

```
this.SetQuery();
```

it will work. There is ***never*** an implicit `this.` with extension methods. Odd but true.

The above explains why `SetQuery()` doesn't work; `base.SetQuery()` won't work, since the extension method is defined for `Page`, not for the base-class. `(this as Page).SetQuery()` will work for the same reasons as `this.SetQuery()`, and actually since `this as Page` is obviously true, the compiler will treat that as a no-op - i.e. `this.SetQuery()` and `(this as Page).SetQuery()` should generate the same IL (as long as the *actual* page doesn't have a more specific `SetQuery()` method, obviously).

Comment: I understand, I think even though I've been quite using extension methods, I've never called them within that class itself. But it still seems to be a bug to me that intellisense shows the method, but it doesn't compile when I write it/select it from intellisense, complaining that it's not found.

Comment: @can yes, that does wound like an intellisense bug - agreed

Comment: FYI: That's only for C#. In VB you can use an implicit this.

Comment: @Scott thanks - I don't know the VB spec very well; good to have that clarification